# force template specialization with an incomplete (partially specified) templated type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am encountering some issues when I try to force template specialization with an incomplete (partially specified) templated type.

Let's consider this oversimplified example:
I have a template function declaration for which I provide forced specification for some common types in the corresponding C++ file.

### in .h file:

```
template <class T>
void doSomething(const T &value);
```

### in cpp file:

```
// force template specializations with various types
template <>
void doSomething<float>(const float &value)
{
  // actual code specialization for type float, es:
  printf("%.3f", value);
}
...
```

and for example, I want to do the same specialization for **glm vector** (from OpenGL Mathematics library), which is templated on the
number of components and on the data type of its components (and also on precision, that I will skip in this example for clarity).

What I would like to avoid is to explicitly write the actual specialization for all possible values of N (leading to code repetition, since it is basically the same loop but with different number of iterations), as shown here:

```
template <>
void doSomething<glm::vec<2, float>>(const glm::vec<2, float> &value)
{
  printf("{");
  printf("%.3f", value[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i< 2 ++i)
    printf(", %.3f", value[i]);
  printf("}");
}

template <>
void doSomething<glm::vec<3, float>>(const glm::vec<3, float> &value)
{
  printf("{");
  printf("%.3f", value[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i< 3 ++i)
    printf(", %.3f", value[i]);
  printf("}");
}

template <>
void doSomething<glm::vec<4, float>>(const glm::vec<4, float> &value)
{
  printf("{");
  printf("%.3f", value[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i< 4 ++i)
    printf(", %.3f", value[i]);
  printf("}");
}
```

What I would like to do is writing something like this:

```
template <glm::length_t N>
void doSomething<glm::vec<N, float>>(const glm::vec<N, float> &value)
{
  printf("{");
  printf("%.3f", value[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i< N ++i)
    printf(", %.3f", value[i]);
  printf("}"); 
}
// force full template specializations
template void doSomething<glm::vec<2, float>>(const glm::vec<2, float> &value);
template void doSomething<glm::vec<3, float>>(const glm::vec<3, float> &value);
template void doSomething<glm::vec<4, float>>(const glm::vec<4, float> &value);
```

but this solution arises the following compilation error:
"illegal use of explicit template arguments"

I have read that "Function partial specialization" is not allowed in C++, is this limitation still valid in modern standards C++ (14/17/20)?
Is this the cause of the issue or maybe I am missing something?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes, partial function specializations are still not allowed.

Comment: *// force template specializations with various types* Function overloading is for such purposes.

Comment: @273K yes the example was an oversimplification, in my actual code the templated type is on the return type. Maybe I should have left it there to give more clarity about the actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Function Specialization is not allowed. However, you can avoid explicitly writing the code for all possible values of N by using Function Overloading. The example below is based on your code, but I've replaced `glm::vec<>` with `std::array<>` since they are similar. Also, I only used a `.C` file for convenience.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

// Overload the function for various types
void doSomething(const float &value)
{
  // actual code for type float:
  printf("%.3f", value);
}

// overloading not specialization
template<std::size_t N>
void doSomething(array<float, N> &value)
{
    printf("{");
    printf("%.3f", value[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        printf(", %.3f", value[i]);
    printf("}");
}

int main()
{
    float f = 5.0;
    doSomething(f);
    cout << endl;

    std::array<float, 3> a1 = {1, 2, 3};
    doSomething<3>(a1);
    cout << endl;

    std::array<float, 4> a2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    doSomething<4>(a2);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ g++ --version
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
$ g++ -std=c++17 doSomething.C 
$ a.out
5.000
{1.000, 2.000, 3.000}
{1.000, 2.000, 3.000, 4.000} 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Luis' answer with overloading, you can also add an additional level of abstraction. You can write a *separate* function that handles the array and then call it from within `doSomething`:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void doSomethingForArray(array<float, N> &value)
{
    printf("{");
    printf("%.3f", value[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        printf(", %.3f", value[i]);
    printf("}");
}

template <>
void doSomething<glm::vec<2, float>>(const glm::vec<2, float> &value)
{ doSomethingForArray(value); }

template <>
void doSomething<glm::vec<3, float>>(const glm::vec<3, float> &value)
{ doSomethingForArray(value); }


template <>
void doSomething<glm::vec<4, float>>(const glm::vec<4, float> &value)
{ doSomethingForArray(value); }
```

Given that your original solution still requires to explicitly instantiate all 3 functions, I don't think this is much of an overhead.